# Why is iframe source code than the source code of file?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, save, blazor

I want to load a file into an iframe, then save it out to a file. Right now, just trying in javascript, but would prefer to use Blazor. Maybe it has newer ways to do it?

Anyway, the source code seems to change a little from the file, but I don't want this as I want to save it out exactly the same as the source. For example, here is some code in the file being loaded into the frame:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en" dir="ltr">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
<!--<![endif]-->
<html>

<head>
```

...and if I load the outerHTML into a textarea to see what would be saved, it is just:

```
<html><head>
```

So ya, any way to get the source from the iframe exactly how it is in the source file? By the way, here is how I currently get the source from the frame into the textarea:

```
<a href="#" onclick="getIframeContent('myI');">
    Get the content of Iframe
</a>

<br />

<textarea id="txtarea" style="width:100%;height:300px"></textarea>
<br>

<iframe id="myI" src="myPage.html" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;"></iframe>

    <script>
        function getIframeContent(myI) {
            var frameObj = document.getElementById(myI);
            var frameContent = frameObj.contentWindow.document.documentElement.outerHTML;
            txtarea.value = frameContent;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Yeah, I would chuck the iframes, nobody uses those anymore.

Comment: what is an alternative / better way?

Comment: Make the content part of the page proper.

Comment: But the functionality is to be able to edit pages that are loaded. So the main page will have a save button in the markup, then the frame or whatever with the page they want to edit via a WYSIWYG

Comment: You should be able to capture whatever you want to save by putting it into a `<div>`.  You don't need an iframe for that.

Comment: Ya but then I don't think it will render as an html page inside that div, which they need to see how it renders to be able to properly edit it